# Page was not found : 'page id' in Episerver

Tags: c#, .net, episerver, episerver-6

I got below error while debugging the code:

> Exception Details: EPiServer.Core.PageNotFoundException: Page 6535 was not found

Please suggest the appropriate solution

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get non-existent page. You can check this code [link](http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/7/984568d4-2b8e-dd49-6d71-13d65d14adaa)

```
new PageReference(int id)
```

Perhaps you need to create it in Edit-mode.

You can get through the start page [link](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Eric-Pettersson/Dates/2013/2/Example-of-baseclass-and-access-to-StartPage-in-your-CMS-7-projects/)

```
ContentReference.StartPage
```

And then get all tree pages and see where missed. http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2013/4/hide-pages-in-the-page-tree-in-episerver-7/

Comment: Thanks for the response
But I could not start my application.
At the start of compilation I got this error

Comment: If you have a call stack or you can look in the debugger it is possible to launch the site will find the answer. I think that the identifiers each has its own pages and hardly anyone can tell what a page has not been created.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens when you start the application it means that the startpage in episerver.config is configured to that ID (and it doesn´t exist), or that you have a page provider configured for this ID (and it doesn´t exist).

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error as soon as you visit your page, just login and go directly to edit mode. It could be that your startpage is pointing to a page that has been deleted or something alike.

So take your host and add /util/login.aspx
That will take you to epi login. Once you are logged in, check your episerverframework.config (depends on which version you have but just try to find out the path to your cms) and see what kind of virtualpath the cms has. Could be /Epiui/cms or something alike.

You might need to add /edit or /admin depending on what you want to reach. But /edit should be your choice in this particular situation.

Then check your startpage for missing pages to see what could be pointing to that page.

It's a late answer but it might help you or someone else out :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a functioning website or is this a new installation? If it's an existing one, go into Episerver's Edit mode (yoursite/episerver/cms/edit/) and use the search (top right of the screen with the magnifying glass icon) and enter the ID (6535) of the page that's missing, the page in question should appear in the search result.